# Error: could not find path

Tags: c#

I have a small problem, which is getting me angry now. I had small mistake in my code, then I found the mistake and everything is running well - almost. I had to find the path to file in the solution and now I found it. But if I open design of the form, it gives me error

"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\Source\ChampsList.txt'"

On the line, where it should be the problem, there is nothing. I can ignore this problem and everything is running well. But still, I hate this:

[image: this]

Thanks

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1083, 569);
        this.Controls.Add(this.guides1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.MainMenu); // this is line where "is" mistake
        this.Controls.Add(this.Panels);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Strip);
        this.MainMenuStrip = this.MainMenu;
        this.Name = "MainProgram";
        this.Text = "Porgram";
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.AppLoad);
        this.MainMenu.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.MainMenu.PerformLayout();
        this.Strip.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.Strip.PerformLayout();
        this.Panels.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
```

Call Stack:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
at HelpApp.Guides.Guides_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Lukáš\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelpApp\HelpApp\Guides.cs:line 28
at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerControlCollection.Add(Control c)
```

Comment: Please provide code, otherwise we're guessing

Comment: Have you previously stored any text file in that path and have you removed it?

Comment: @freefaller: error is shown in this section of code - yes, in designer :/

Comment: @coder: no, i have mistake in this path, then i changed it and this happened

Comment: You can open the .Designer.cs file with ordinary text editor like Notepad. Do it and remove the offensive part where the non existent file is mentioned.

Comment: Please use `@` when replying to comments e.g. @Crooker otherwise people won't see you replied.

Comment: Also, please post here the full stack trace, click "Show Call Stack" to view it.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard the line where should be problem is marked in code above by comment, path in error is nowhere in code, if i delete it, error still on same line

Comment: What is line 28 in the file "Guides.cs"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard & others :thanks for help, now working good, it show that error is on line 141, but it was in 140, which open another form, and there was error, i just remove it, and recreated it and now it works well

Comment: @ShadowWizard and yes, there was a problem :)